# Can we share App class in Today- Widget-Extension

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget

I am developing an application where I have to use my some class in Today- Widget-Extension. But I am not getting any way to access those class. 
Is it possible to access application class in Today- Widget-Extension.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. First you need to set targets of your class to both aplication and extension. Second you need to put `public` keyword to your class. You can read more on that [here](http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/swift-programming-101-understanding-access-control).